# Attach event handler in chrome not working

Tags: events, google-chrome, datepicker, handler

This code:

```
function attachDateNavEventHandler() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-title option').each(function () {
    $(this).mouseup(setFlag);
});
```

attaches the event fine in FF but not in IE 8 or Chrome.  I'm working with the jQuery datepicker and want to set a flag if the user navigates with the month or year drop-downs.  I can't seem to attach to the onchange event of the selects.  I think there must be an internal block on those events.  I also had trouble using a simple click 
Any suggestions mooooooost welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).on('mouseup', setFlag);
```

Though this is basically the same thing you have.

I have a feeling that the options themselves may have the funny business. Options can't do everything that a typical HTML element can, but I'm not certain of the limitations on what browsers.

What about setting an on change on the whole select itself instead of trying to listen for mouseup events of each individual option.

```
  $('.ui-datepicker-title').change(
```